# UITableView resize for iPad / iPhone 5,6,6+

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";
  CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  // 
}
```

The CustomTableViewCell is set up in a NIB with the following layout:

- ContentView

  - UIView (placeholderView)

    - UIImageView (customImageView)

I'd like the ContentView/UIView/UIImageView to resize according to the width of the device used to display the UITableView. Its been possible to resize the UITableView (but I've had to set the frame of the UITableView in a subclass of UITableView in layoutSubviews as the UITableView kept resetting to a smaller frame)

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
}
```

and I've set the size of each view in the NIB in the Custom class after subclassing layoutSubviews:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{

    float cellHeight = ...;

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.paddingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, screenRect.size.width, 10 );

    self.placeholderView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, cellHeight);
    self.customImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, cellHeight);    
}
```

but this only seems to work for every third row in the UITableView.

This seems a convoluted way to set the width - is there a simpler way to do this and is there an explanation for why this only works on every third row?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It will be wiser to use Autolayout, just set the constraints in the Interface Builder. Give the constraints for the tableview from all sides with the superview. Similarly give constraints to the custom cell. The cell and the tableview will resize according to the device width itself.

Give the constraints to the tableview as follows : Leading to Superview, Trailing to Superview, Top to Superview, Bottom to Superview

[image]

Similarly give constraints to the imageView in the tableView Cell : Leading to Superview, Trailing to Superview, Top to Superview, Bottom to Superview

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are the constraints I should add?